# Can't understand そんな労カかけないでもらいたいなっていうね

Tags: words

In this video clip (https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxY2iqi7hqFjIGJ0iJnKH18P5fzS8ugw0z?si=HQvGDGUYUckQ_EDi), I cannot break down (what words are composing the sentence) what the man says.

> そんなあんまなんかこう、自分のためにそんな労カかけないでもらいたいなっていうね。

Here, そんな労カかけないでも means 'without putting such effort', but what is らいたいなっていうね? Does he mean "I think it can be said to be らいたい"? I couldn't find the word らいたい in the dictionary.

Comment: More 'easy' Japanese'. In what world is this easy I wonder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are breaking the sentence in the wrong place. It's not かけないでも + らいたい,  it's かけないで + もらいたい.

Things you may already know:

Adding たい to the masu-stem of the a verb means 'want to verb'. The verb here is もらう, so もらいたい is 'want to receive'. Adding もらう to the て-form of a verb means 'receive *the favour of* someone doing the verb for you'. The whole lot is "I want to receive them not putting in such effort ", or more naturally, "I don't want them to put in such effort for me".

Comment: Ah~ that was  it. Thanks a  lot!